# Disable button in unity without changing its transparency

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I have noticed that when I set the interactable property of button to false the button alpha decreases. Does anybody have knowledge on how to achieve this in Unity .

```
 myButton.interactable = false;
```

It would be immensely helpful if you could help !

Thank you !

Answer (score 7):

You have to change the "Disabled Color" of the Button component. Check the alpha value.
[image]

In order to change it by code :

```
// Unfortunately, you can't do button.colors.disabledColor.a = 1 ;
UnityEngine.UI.ColorBlock colors = button.colors ;
Color disabledColor = colors.disabledColor ;
disabledColor.a = 1 ;
colors.disabledColor = disabledColor ;
button.colors = colors ;
```